# How to extract key phrases from customer service?

Tags: python, nlp, google-colaboratory, nltk, text-extraction

So, I have a csv file about customer service (like, why they called). I want to extract key words and visualize it. But upon thinking about it more, I realize that I should be extracting key phrases. But I'm not sure what's the best way to do this since... well, it's customer service. People call about the same issue, but say different things which messes with the key phrase extraction (ex. wifi issue, problem with internet, connectivity issue, etc.). In addition, the sentence are inconsistent. Like, I have a sentence that says: 'password reset request; customer called to request password reset' and another that says: 'auto collision; hit and run' or 'auto collision; collision, no injuries'. At least for the first sentence, I can extract password reset, but what am I suppose to extract for the last two? Auto collision? Do I ignore the specifics? Any ideas about how to extract these kind of phrases?

Answer (score 0):

A straightforward approach of tokenization and visualizing top words would be a good starting point, for example, using `sklearn`:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer

# Read in the csv
df = pd.read_csv('customer_service.csv')

# Vectorize the text
cv = CountVectorizer()
vectorized = cv.fit_transform(df['text'])

# Convert to dense dataframe with tokens as column names
word_df = pd.DataFrame(vectorized.toarray(), columns=cv.get_feature_names_out())

# Sum to find most frequently occuring tokens and visualize top 10
word_df.sum().nlargest(10).sort_values().plot(kind='barh')
plt.show()
```

Note I am assuming your file is called `customer_service.csv` and has two fields, `id` and `text`.

You'll still get some good insights - even in the example you provided, the two sentences both contained the word "collision". But, of course, this all depends on what you are trying to do.

If you're looking at more advanced approaches, there are ways to do key phrase extraction, either with python libraries such as spaCy or [using web services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/ai-services/language-service/key-phrase-extraction/tutorials/integrate-power-bi), but these more involved.